# How to call instance of variety of classes in java

Tags: java, class

I create a class to handle some specific job that use variety of classes on my project.

But after finish the job class must call-back specific method on the called classes.

I use interface to handle this call-back method.

How can I store the called class?

I can get the instance from constructor but I'm looking for generic way.

Comment: Hi, please add some code, so the SO-Community can help you better

Comment: Hi. i'm looking for calling back method or way. fortunately my code little big to posting here.

Comment: You want to log what are the functions called?

Comment: Reflection could help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: What do you mean by "store the called class" ? adding code to your question would be better!!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but it may be possible that you have missed the fact that classes can implement more than one interface.

```
public interface DoesAJob {

    public void doIt();
}

public interface Finishes {

    public void finish();
}

class AThing implements DoesAJob, Finishes {

    @Override
    public void doIt() {

    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {

    }

}

private void doTheJob(DoesAJob thing) {
    thing.doIt();
}

private void finishUp(Finishes thing) {
    thing.finish();
}

public void test() {
    AThing thing = new AThing();
    doTheJob(thing);
    finishUp(thing);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just Java Interface, or use Java Reflection.

First the Interface

```
package test;

public interface MyClassInterface {
    public String getName();
}
```

next, the Interface Implementation

```
    package test;

    public class MyClassImplementation implements MyClassInterface {
        String name;

        public MyClassImplementation() {
            name= "Whatever";
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

finally invoke the class. just Interface example:

```
    package test;

    public class MainTest {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            MyClassInterface myClassImplementation = new MyClassImplementation();
            System.out.println(myClassImplementation.getName());
        }
    }
```

Using Reflection example:

```
    package test;

    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;

    public class MainTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
                throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
                InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException  {

            //using reflection
            Object otherClassImplementation=null;
            try {
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName("test.MyClassImplementation");
                otherClassImplementation = cls.newInstance();

                Method method = cls.getMethod("getName");
                System.out.println(method.invoke(otherClassImplementation)); 

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```